# Change values of a Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add my `items` values on the existing `f['ECPM_medio']` column
I made some modifications on the `items values` to have `0.8 to 0.9`values of each numbers. the problem is when I try to add these new numbers to the existing column... I paste the same number on all rows!

```
import pandas as pd

jf = pd.read_csv("Cliente_x_Pais_Sitio.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
del jf['Fill_rate']
del jf['Importe_a_pagar_a_medio']
a = jf.sort_values(by=["Cliente","Auth_domain","Sitio",'Country'])
f = a.groupby(["Cliente","Auth_domain","Sitio","Country"], as_index=False)['ECPM_medio'].min()
del a['Fecha']
del a['Subastas']
del a['Impresiones_exchange']
f.to_csv('Recom_Sitios.csv', index=False)




for item in f['ECPM_medio']:
    item = float(item)
    if item <= 0.5:
        item = item * 0.8
    else:
        item = item * 0.9
    item = float("{0:.2f}".format(item))
    item

for item in item:
f['ECPM_medio'] = item


f.to_csv('Recom_Sitios22.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function and then apply it with lambda.

Example:

```
def myfunc(item):
    item = float(item)
    if item <= 0.5:
        item = item * 0.8
    else:
        item = item * 0.9
    item = float("{0:.2f}".format(item))
    return item

f['ECPM_medio'] = f['ECPM_medio'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

Comment: Can I remove the function and do it without def??

Comment: oh geez don't loop via `apply` for something like.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you could also do something like this:

```
f.loc[:, 'ECPM_medio'] = (f['ECPM_medio'] * \
                          np.where(f['ECPM_medio'] <= 0.5, .8, .9)).round(2)
```

`np.where(f['ECPM_medio'] <= 0.5, .8, .9)` returns an array the length of your `ECPM_medio` column with values `.8` or `.9`, depending on the same-indexed value in f['ECPM_medio']. You can then multiply your DataFrame column by this array, and wrap the whole expression in parentheses so that you can take the resulting Series (i.e. your transformed `f['ECPM_medio']` column), and tack on `.round(2)` to round the column's values to two places.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Pandas vectorized operations,

```
df['ECPM_medio'] = np.where(df['ECPM_medio'] <= 0.5, df['ECPM_medio'] * 0.8, df['ECPM_medio']* 0.9)
```